# How to eliminate negative space in div element?

Tags: html, css

Cannot figure out how to eliminate this space right above my text in my box, the text stays static when I change height.

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <title> :/</title>
        <style>
          h1 {
              color: white;
              font-size: 1000%;
          }
        div {
            width: 200em;
            height: 110em;
            background-color: red;
        }
        </style>
      </head>
      <body>
          <div><h1>not workin :(</h2></div>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: you mean the space above the red box?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title> :/</title>
    <style>
      h1 {
          color: white;
          font-size: 1rem;
         }

    div {
        display:flex ;
        align-items:center ;
        width: 50vw;
        height: 80vh;
        background-color: red;
    }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
      <div><h1>not workin :(</h1></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

try this out